# Complexity of matrix inverse via Gaussian elimination

Tags: time-complexity, matrices, linear-algebra

I'm trying to determine the exact complexity of finding an $n\times n$ matrix inverse of $A$.
If it is known that the complexity of Gaussian elimination is $\frac{2}{3}n^3 + \frac{1}{2}n^2+O(n)$, then is it true that the complexity of finding $A^{-1}$ should be about twice same, since we are effectively doing two sets of Gaussian eliminations in parallel plus some row interchanges and multiplications?

Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: [Also posted on Math.SE](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1868957/14578).
Please [do not post the same question on multiple sites](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068). Each community should have an honest shot at answering without anybody's time being wasted.

Answer (score 1):

No, it's not true.  You *can* use Gaussian elimination to invert a matrix in $O(n^3)$ time, but there are other algorithms that are even faster.  The complexity of a problem is the running time of the *fastest* algorithm for that problem.  Therefore, it is not correct that the complexity of matrix inversion is $\Theta(n^3)$.

See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_elimination#Computational_efficiency, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_multiplication_algorithm, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computational_complexity_of_mathematical_operations#Matrix_algebra, https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/q/22105/4274, [Complexity class of Matrix Inversion](https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/38353/755).